# BindException: Address already in use - With many outbound connections

Tags: java, client-server

I have created a service that opens a lots of remote resources; for a lot, i mean over 200k / day, but i think that less than 1000 connections are opened at the same time. After i connect to the remote resource, i open an input stream to get the file content.
Sometimes i get the following exception

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at sitodove.varie.ExternalLinksChecker.getWebPage(ExternalLinksChecker.java:121)
at sitodove.varie.ExternalLinksChecker.run(ExternalLinksChecker.java:37)
```

This service starts correctly, opening just a few ports for limited needs because it needs to offer some services. While it is running, i get the above exception, what may be the cause?

Comment: The port might be in use by a different service which might not even be part of your application. For example sometimes an NVidia driver blocks the standard JNDI port 1099 on our machines.

Comment: The problem is that i never specify a port, i just ask to read a remote file and a port is (i suppose) taken automatically.

Comment: The automatic process could still run into conflicts so you should try and check which port range is used and whether there are other applications that might use ports in that range.

Comment: Should i really insert an infinite while trying to download from an inputstream..?

Comment: I don't get your question, where's the infinite while involved?

Comment: I mean: the getInputStream generates an error, so what should i do? Try again to get the InputStream? But... what if it fails again? I actually don't know what ports are in use, because the 99% of them are choosen within a second and closed some seconds later

Comment: No what I meant is you should manually check whether _another_ application might interfere here. In your code you might be able to just allow a certain number of services and put any request that cannot be handled immediately into a queue. That way you could limit the possibility that your application itself uses the entire port range and then fails.

Answer (score 0):

A port is already being used and you try to bind it again. Check in your application if your are not trying to use a port twice.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you're trying to open a port that is already open.
open the terminal an type telnet   to see if that port is already open. ie.

telnet localhost 9889

Trying ::1...

telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
if this command returns  Connection refused, that means the port is free.